# File upload from google drive using cordova file transfer gives empty file path in ionic2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic2

I am using cordova file transfer for uploading images and docs. this is working fine for selecting images or docs from the devices, but when i am selecting image or doc from google drive am geeting an empty fileuri.My code is as

```
 doc_capture(page, mediatype, id?) {

    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 75,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      targetWidth: 300,
      targetHeight: 300,
      correctOrientation: true,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      mediaType: mediatype == 'PICTURE' ? 0 : 2
    }

    return this.camera.getPicture(options).then((fileUri) => {

      let filePath;
      if (mediatype == 'PICTURE' && this.plt.is('android')) {
        filePath = fileUri.substr(0, fileUri.lastIndexOf('?'));
      } else {
        filePath = fileUri;
      }
      return this.file_upload(filePath, page, id)
    }, err => {
      return Promise.reject('');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you targeting only android devices?

Comment: @VicJordan . No. for both android and iOS